# how get the result from cmd

Tags: excel, vba

I am  trying vba code to open cmd and do some stuff and after i get the result .

This is for the automate the process to connect to server and request a query and get result to store in excel sheet.

```
Sub hello()
Dim oShell As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oOutput As Object
Dim oExec As Object



oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
SendKeys "plink.exe -ssh username@ipaddress -pw password"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
SendKeys "run sql select n.dnorpattern as Directory_Number, n.description as "
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))
SendKeys "%{F4}", True

'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
 Dim s As String
 Dim sLine As String
 While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
 sLine = oOutput.ReadLine

 If sLine <> "" Then MsgBox sLine
 Wend
```

I am trying this code to get output but failed

```
Set oOutput = oShell.StdOut
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [Craig Pearson's Shell and Wait](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx) function?